# MySQL does not work after installation

Tags: python, mysql

Hi I am new to Python as well as database implementation. After installing MySQL and trying to import it in my Python script (import MySQLdb), but I got this in return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/opsu/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/src/Test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
 ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

1 suggestion I got from google was to uninstall python 64bit and install python 32 bit. However I am also using wxPython 64bit so I cannot do this. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: which version of python are you using 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Your only option around this problem is to install the 32 bit of Python and use that with the 32 bit MySQL version you have.

Comment: @Ankit I am using 2.7

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but will it afftect my wxPython? Do i have to change wxPython to 32bit also?

Comment: You could also try using a 64 bit version of MySQL which will play friendly with your current Python installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I downloaded the 64 bit mysql and it worked :D